# not able to connect with the kafka in docker using docker-file

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-producer-api

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - ./.docker-volumes/zookeeper/_data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./.docker-volumes/zookeeper/_log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./.docker-volumes/kafka/_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

Above is the docker-compose file to spin up the zookeeper and kafka instances in docker.

When I run the service which is trying to make a connection with the kafka. I'm getting below error. I tracked it down on the internet but did not get much on this.

**Error on the Service-layer**

```
.12:43:18.730 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. 
.12:43:19.295 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. 
.12:43:19.481 [kafka-admin-client-thread | vendor_srs_consumer_srs_restaurant_finance_pan_validate_client_id_0] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=vendor_srs_consumer_srs_restaurant_finance_pan_validate_client_id_0] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.
```

**Error in Docker when kafka-producer is trying to connect with the kafka brokers.**

```
[2021-07-12 07:13:19,492] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=1] Unexpected error from /172.20.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369296129 larger than 104857600)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:105)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:893)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:792)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Not sure why producer is not able to connect with the broker.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092` is not a valid advertised listener; this needs to be a resolvable address.

In your error, `Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) terminated`, unclear where this code is running, but if on the same host outside of Docker, then you should advertise `localhost`, not `0.0.0.0`

Your other error, `InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369296129 larger than 104857600)` indicates that you have connected to some other server and got a response that the client did not expect.

Comment: Turns out that the issue was with latest docker desktop app. I downgraded the version and issue got vanished. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initially they are on default bridge network, and in order to communicate between the containers you have to use container IPs.

You can try deploying both of the containers on same network.

Add a network definition in your docker-compose

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: zookeeper-kafka
  zookeeper-kafka:
    driver: bridge
```

In services definition you can add network name and ports.

Example, for zookeeper service

```
zookeeper:
    networks:
    - zookeeper-kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - ./.docker-volumes/zookeeper/_data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./.docker-volumes/zookeeper/_log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
```

And then you can access zookeeper service via zookeeper-kafka:2181 (i.e. network-name:port), while connecting through kafka.

Example for update kafka service definition

```
kafka:
    networks:
    - zookeeper-kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-kafka:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://zookeeper-kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./.docker-volumes/kafka/_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

Hopefully this helps you

Comment: No. I'm aware of the bridges in docker. It's not related to the bridges.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced same problem, we use kafka container for running functional tests dealing with producers or consumers.

Here is snippet from docker-compose.yml where the containers for zookeeper, kafka and schema registries are provided

```
zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z zookeeper 2181
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      # Default 8080 port clashes with existing services
      KAFKA_OPTS: '-Dzookeeper.admin.serverPort=3181'


kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.0
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z kafka 29092
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1


schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.1.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z schema-registry 8081
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
```

Now as you can see in the **kafka** container

```
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
```

the security protocol the container is exposing was PLAINTEXT.

However in my case, the problem was in the application.yaml file. Below is the kafka producer config in application.yaml. Now as its mentioned security protocol to be SASL_SSL

```
 kafka:
        producer:
          bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER:}
          key-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
          value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
        properties:
          schema.registry.url: ${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:}
          sasl:
            jaas:
              config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='${KAFKA_CLUSTER_API_KEY:}' password='${KAFKA_CLUSTER_SECRET:}';
            mechanism: PLAIN
          basic:
            auth:
              user:
                info: ${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_API_KEY:}:${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SECRET:}
              credentials:
                source: USER_INFO
          security:
            protocol: SASL_SSL
```

So, in order to run my functional tests, I had to override this security protocol to PLAINTEXT. As this is only needed for functional test, and in production configuration SASL_SSL is the right thing.

And the way we can override is by setting an environment variable named `SPRING_KAFKA_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL`  this is equivalent to (Spring resolves this implicitly)

```
spring:
    kafka:
       properties:
          security:
              protocol: PLAINTEXT
```

And thus, in functional test mode, application was able to connect to the kafka container by overriding the security protocol from **SASL_SSL** to **PLAINTEXT**